# Android Studio + DDMS error "Failed to push selection: Read-only file system"

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I recently was forced into using Android Studio. Before that I have worked with eclipse and never had issues with DDMS of any sort. Now I am attempting to push a file or create a folder on the emulator device and I keep getting this error:

> Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

I messed around with some of the file read only permisions and I managed to generate this message for a little bit.

> Failed to push selection: Permission denied

My operating system is windows.

**EDIT:**

I tried to create an external SDCard image, and the error I get now when attempting to push a file is:

> [timestamp] Failed to push the item(s).
>
> [timestamp] null