# Can't push files to SD card in Android emulator in API 25

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-device-monitor

I have been testing my app on Android emulator with an API version of 23 which works very well, but in other versions it doesn't work as well.
I need to push some files into the downloads directory, and so far it hasn't worked on an emulator running API 25.
The logcat of Android Device Monitor is constantly spammed with all sorts of messages.

[Errors in Android device monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWQT6.jpg)

I was able to get the error

[timestamp] Failed to push the item(s).

[timestamp] null

before restarting Android Studio, but since I restarted I can't find a message like this. So my problem seems to have something in common with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224665/android-studio-ddms-error-failed-to-push-selection-read-only-file-system)

Comment: Have you tried using an actual device to see if the problem persists there as well ? Download and install ADB and turn on USB debugging on your device and connect it to your computer via usb to test your app.

Comment: I have an Xperia Z1 but I have never been able to successfully connect it. I have tried to root it and also connect it to Android Studio but there are always countless errors encountered with adb, which I have been unable to resolve.

Comment: Try the solution given by Tim, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you finding the download directory? If you're using a hard path (e.g. `/.../Downloads/`) you shouldn't, instead use the storage APIs. This is because multi-users are introduced which breaks using a hard path.

More specifically, you probably want to use [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Enviornment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

For more info on storage, [see the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)